# Connectedness in the product topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

Consider two connected topology spaces $X$ and $Y$, and a connected subset $A\subset X\times Y$. Then take $I\subset X$ connected, can we claim that
$$A\cap (I\times Y)$$
is connected?

Came up with this question while thinking of an easy way to show that the graph of a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is connected iff the graph of $f|_I$ is connected whenever $I$ is connected (it is an interval).

Comment: Consider $X = Y = \mathbb{R}$ and take a $\subset$-shaped subset (or a circle, an annulus, …) for $A$. You need to use a few more facts about graphs of functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Let $X=Y=[0,1]$ for simplicity, and let $A$ be the circle inscribed in $X\times Y$.  Then subinterval $I = [1/4,3/4] \subset X$ is connected, but:

$$  A \cap (I\times Y) $$

is not connected, as it consists of two separate arcs of the circle.